# XPath: How to check if an attribute exists?

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the following XML, how do I write an XPath query to pull nodes where the attribute `foo` exists?:

```
<node1>
  <node2>
    <node3 foo='bar'></node3>
    <node3></node3>
    <node3 bar='foo'></node3>
    <node3 foo='foobar'></node3>
  </node2>
</node1>
```

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Short and sweet:

```
//*[@foo]
```

Of course you should use a more specific expression. But with `[@attributeName]` you get all nodes which have that attribute.

Answer (score 41):

Use the following XPath expression

```
//*[boolean(@foo)]
```

Comment: This was helpful in the case where it was part of a larger boolean expression, i.e. `//button[@id='foo' and boolean(@disabled)]`

Answer (score 12):

If you use and xpath, this maybe can help you:

```
count(//*[@foo])
```

it will return count of node/child that have attribute foo