# Python web-scraping with changing href

Tags: python, web-scraping, tags, href

I have been scraping some websites using Python 2.7

```
    page = requests.get(URL)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

    prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="product-price"]/text()')
    titles = tree.xpath('//span[@class="product-title"]/text()')
```

This works fine for websites that have these clear tags in them but a lot of the websites I encounter have the following HTML setup:

```
<a href="https://www.retronintendokopen.nl/gameboy/games/gameboy-classic/populous" class="product-name"><strong>Populous</strong></a>
```

(I am tyring to extract the title: Populous)
Where an href changes for every title I am extracting, I have tried the following for the above example hoping it would see the class and that would be enough but that doesn't work

```
titles = tree.xpath('//a[@class="product-name"]/text()')
```

I was searching for a character that would work like *, as in 'I don't care what's in here, just take everything with a href=.. But couldn't find anything

```
titles = tree.xpath('//a[@href="*"]/text()')
```

Also, would I need to specify that there is also class= in the a tag like

```
titles = tree.xpath('//a[@href="*" @class="product-name"]/text()')
```

EDIT: I also found a fix if there are only changing tags in the a path using

```
titles = tree.xpath('//h3/a/@title')
```

example for this tag

```
<h3><a href="http://www.a-retrogame.nl/index.php?id_product=5843&amp;controller=product&amp;id_lang=7" title="4 in 1 fun pack">4 in 1 fun pack</a></h3>
```

Comment: try beautifulsoup

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737906/xpath-how-to-check-if-an-attribute-exists and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247978/xpath-with-multiple-conditions

Comment: @nishantkumar no! beautifulsoup is not an ideal solution for scraping. `xpaths` are!.

Comment: try scrapy. also, in xpath //a[@href] is used to prove existence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
titles = tree.xpath('//a[@class="product-name"]//text()')
```

notice `//` after class selector.

Comment: That was too easy haha, could you explain what the double operator actually does and the single didn't work?

Comment: @Alex double `//` means `any indirect child` i.e you can observe that after `<a>` there is `<strong>`. so xpath couldn't find your `text` content as it was expecting it to be as `immediate` child of `<a>` . that is why we need to have `//`. hope it clears